# How to add another TabBarItem after the TabBarController has loaded it's view

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, dynamically-generated

I want to be able to add a new `TabBarItem` after a certain condition has been met. So initially the app has two `TabBarItems`, but if you choose to sign in as an admin I want a third `TabBarItem` to be shown

I can add the `TabBarItem` fine in the `viewDidLoad` of my `TabBarController` which extends `UITabBarController`. But if I add a function called `addNewTabBar` which calls the exact same code, the code gets executed but the view doesn't get updated.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
//        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Data", bundle: nil)
//        let roomChooserVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "roomchooser") as! RoomChooserController
//        roomChooserVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .downloads, tag: 3)
//        self.viewControllers?.append(roomChooserVC)
//
//        ^^^^IF I ADD THE TAB IN VIEWDIDLOAD IT WORKS FINE ^^^

    }

// If I call addNewTabBarItem() from another class, the methods get executed but the new tab is not shown ---

    func addNewTabBarItem(){
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Data", bundle: nil)
        let roomChooserVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "roomchooser") as! RoomChooserController
        roomChooserVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .downloads, tag: 3)
        self.viewControllers?.append(roomChooserVC)
    }
}
```

Now in the class in which I call the method from (omitted some of the irrelevant code

```
let tbController = TabBarController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tbController.addNewTabBarItem()
        // If I put a breakpoint in addNewTabBarItem everything's get 
        // executed fine
        // MAYBE RELOAD VIEW OF TABBARCONTROLLER SOMEHOW?
}
```

Comment: You try to get your `TabBarController`, but you got a new one another. You should to get your first instance of `TabBarController`.

Answer (score 0):

You try to get your `TabBarController`, but you got a new one another. You should to get your instance of `TabBarController`. You can reach it with several ways. For simplicity, I suggest to you one of them.

At first, declare var `main` in your `TabBarController`:

```
static var main : TabBarController? = nil
```

On `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` add a code:

```
TabBarController.main = self // a part of 'singletone' approach
```

and in your another controller use:

```
TabBarController.main?. addNewTabBarItem()
```

It's important that your class uses for single instance.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your first tab's view controller:

```
let tbController = TabBarController()
```

creates a ***new*** instance of `TabBarController` -- it doesn't provide access to the *existing* instance.

So, in your first tab's view controller:

```
class HjelmslundFirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // this gets a reference to the existing custom TabBarController
        if let tbc = self.tabBarController as? TabBarController {
            tbc.addNewTabBarItem()
        }

    }

}
```

As a note, you should always unwrap optionals, and check for valid objects. So, in your custom `TabBarController` class:

```
func addNewTabBarItem(){

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Data", bundle: nil)

    if let roomChooserVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "roomchooser") as? RoomChooserController {
        roomChooserVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .downloads, tag: 3)
        self.viewControllers?.append(roomChooserVC)
    }

}
```

Of course, you'll also want to add error-handling code in case the `if` conditions fail.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that makes sense actually, I don't know how I missed that. About the unwrapping thing, yeah, for sure, this was just a "quick" fixie to try it out, but appreciate that advice as well.